Show that $\mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq 2}$ has a two dimensional subspace contained in the orthogonal complement of the subspace
Let $V=\mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq 2}$, and let $f$ the bilinear form given by $f(p,q)=\int_{-1}^{1} xp(x)q(x)dx.$ Find a basis $B$ of $V$ such that $[f]_B$ is diagonal, and show that $V$ has a subspace $U$ of dimension $2$ such that $U\subset U^{\perp}$.

First, consider the basis $C=\{1,x,x^2\}$ of $V$. The matrix of $f$ with respect to $C$ is
$$A=[f]_C=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2/3 &0\\
2/3 & 0 & 2/5\\
0 & 2/5& 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Doing row and column operations on $A$, eventually I got that $$P^TAP=\begin{pmatrix} 4/3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -16/27 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},$$
with $P=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2/3 & 64/135\\
1 & -2/3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -64/81
\end{pmatrix}$.
So, I can consider the basis $B=\left\{1+x, \frac{2}{3}(1-x), \frac{-64}{81}x^2+\frac{64}{135}\right\}$. And clearly, $[f]_B=P^TAP$ is a diagonal matrix, so the first part of the exercise is done.
Now, how do I show that $V$ has a subspace $U$ with dim$U=2$ and $U\subset U^{\perp}$?

You found a non-zero polynomial $q$ such that $f(p,q)=0$ for all $p$. I would try and find another polynomial $r$ such that $f(r,r)=0$. Then look at the span of $r$ and $q$.
